# What is the intuition behind R squared of linear regression? from the perspective of vector projection

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, intuition, numerical-linear-algebra, regression

[image]

I copied this photo from [Anupam Kundu's answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-intuition-behind-the-least-squared-regression-formula).

As explained on Quora, linear regression can be imagined as a projection from the dependent variable on the hypo plane defined by the columns of $X$ matrix.

Now,  if go one step further, what is the geometric meaning of $R^{2}$ in such projection? Can anyone share some ideas?

Comment: I don't see $R$ in the picture.  What does it mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination , R squared is a common approach to describe the linear relationship

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can see the $R^2$ in this illustration since it is a a so-called "dimensionless" scalar
$$
R^2 = \frac{Y^T(H-\frac{1}{n}J)Y}{Y^T(1-J\frac{1}{n})Y} =
 1 - \frac{Y^T(I-H)Y}
{Y^T(1-J\frac{1}{n})Y},
$$
where $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is the projection matrix onto the column space of $X$, and $J = \mathrm{1}\mathrm{1}^T$.